# How many characters can you store in a binary(64)

Tags: sql-server, passwords, disaster-recovery

I have a procedure used to authenticate users in my db and it never crossed my mind to determine how long of an password a user could have in the db.  I'm at the point where if someone wants to have a 100 char password, so be it, but I'm thinking I want to use this to account recovery questions as well.

Here is my procedure:

```
declare @PasswordHash nvarchar(100)
    = 'ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|ThisIs101|'
DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = Newid();
declare @passwordHast binary(64) = (
                                       select Hashbytes('SHA2_512', @PasswordHash + Cast(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36)))
                                   );

if (@passwordHast = Hashbytes('SHA2_512', @PasswordHash + Cast(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))))
begin
    select 1
end
else
begin
    select 0
end
```

Just to put it out there, in the use case for recovery passwords, there will be a system password not kept in the DB, however if there is a better way, i'm all ears.

Comment: You are storing the hash of the password - not the password itself so there is no practical limit to the length of the password itself. The `@input` to `hashbytes` can be anything up to the 2 billion character length supported by  `varchar(max)`

Comment: @MartinSmith I totally understand max, I was just wondering about 64

Comment: If you hash a 2GB string with SHA2_512 you will still get back a `binary(64)`

Comment: The 64 means 64 bytes. If you are implicitly/explicitly converting to a string based value to a binary value, then that's 64 bytes of characters. You aren't doing that here though, as mentioned.

Comment: @MartinSmith Must be said that for SQL2014 and earlier the max length was 8000 bytes.

Comment: I would advice against using the sql server itself to generate hashes of passwords. While SHA2 is better than MD5, it's nowadays better to use better algos like i dunno, PBKDF2, which do a lot of iterations and extends keys properly. So it's better if your application generates the password hash and only use sql server to store them and compare against existing binary hashes.